# Creating an abstract syntax tree from a stack

Tags: c

I'm working on a project where I need to do evaluate a reverse polish notation expression or convert the rpn expression to infix notation. I am doing this by pushing all of the elements of the expression onto a stack then popping each element from the stack and inserting it into an abstract syntax tree. From there I will traverse the tree to complete the evaluate and convert operations. Here is what I have so far

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct snode 
{
  char datum;
  struct snode* bottom;
};

struct tnode
{
  char datum;
  struct tnode* left;
  struct tnode*right;
};

struct snode* 
push(struct snode* stack, char x) {
  struct snode *S = (struct snode*)malloc(sizeof(struct snode));
  S->datum = x;
  S->bottom = stack;
  return S;
}

struct snode* 
pop(struct snode* stack) {
  struct snode *S;
  if (stack == NULL)
    return NULL;
  S = stack->bottom;
  free(stack);
  return S;
}

char
peek(struct snode* stack){
  return stack->datum;
}


struct tnode*
create_node(char x){
  struct tnode* tmp;
  tmp = (struct tnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
  tmp->datum = x;
  tmp->right = NULL;
  tmp->left = NULL;
  return tmp;
}

void
print_table(struct tnode *AST){
  if(AST !=NULL){
    print_table(AST->left);
    printf("%c ", AST->datum);
    print_table(AST->right);
  }
}



struct tnode*
build_tree(struct snode *S)
{

  struct tnode* root;
  if (S == NULL)
    return NULL;

  char top = peek(S);

  if (top == 'A' || top == 'S' || top == 'X' || top == 'D' || top == 'M')
    {
      root = create_node(top);
      S = pop(S); 
      root->right = build_tree(S);
      S = pop(S);
      root->left = build_tree(S);
      return root;
    } 

  root= create_node(top);

  return root;
}


int
main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

  int i = 1;
  struct tnode *tree = NULL;
  struct snode *stack = NULL;

  char value;
  while (argv[i]!= NULL)
    {
      value = argv[i][0];
      stack = push(stack, value);
      i++;
    }


  tree =  build_tree(stack);
  print_table(tree);
  printf("\n");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My problem is that this code only doesnt work for every rpn expression. For Example:

```
./project 7 4 A 3 S
```

outputs

```
7 A 4 S 3
```

which is correct. but

```
./project 1 2 X 3 4 X A
```

outputs

```
A 3 X 4
```

which is clearly not correct. Im pretty sure my problem is in my build_tree function, but I have no idea on how I could do a build_tree in a different way.
Also, when I have an expression such as

```
./project 12 3 D 2 D
```

how come the output is

```
1 D 3 D 2
```

instead of

```
12 D 3 D 2
```

Thank you for all help. Any input on how I could change my code to make the rest of the project simpler is also appreciated!

Comment: Aren't you going to need some braces in that infix notation to control expression evaluation orders?

Comment: right now im just getting to a point where I know the tree is being built correctly @NikolaiNFetissov

Comment: `1` vs `12` in you last example is easy - you are using only the first character of each `argv[i]`.

Comment: The first one errors due to missing check for `*` operator in your `if` statement in tree building function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the "updates" to the stack are not remembered when you descend more than one level in your `build_tree()` function. When you do for example `root->right = build_tree(S);` and you pop the stack in context of that call to `build_tree()`, the stack hasn't actually been popped in context of the caller.

I would suggest that you alter your functions according to something like this:

```
void
pop(struct snode **stack) {
  struct snode *S;
  if (*stack == NULL)
    return;

  S = (*stack)->bottom;
  free(*stack);
  *stack = S;
}


struct tnode*
build_tree(struct snode **S)
{

  struct tnode* root;
  if (*S == NULL)
    return NULL;

  char top = peek(*S);

  if (top == 'A' || top == 'S' || top == 'X' || top == 'D' || top == 'M')
    {
      root = create_node(top);
      pop(S); 
      root->right = build_tree(S);
      pop(S);
      root->left = build_tree(S);
      return root;
    } 

  root = create_node(top);

  return root;
}

int
main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  ...

  tree =  build_tree(&stack);

  ...
}
```

The difference becomes more obvious if you add a `printf()` call to `peek()` where you output the datum of the visited stack node.

For your other error, where `./project 12 3 D 2 D` doesn't work, and `12` is replaced with `1`, I would suggest that you use the `atoi()` function to convert a string to an integer, instead of just `value = argv[i][0]`. You could test if `value` is a digit, and if so do `value = atoi(argv[i])` afterwards.

In addition, as already commented on by [Nikolai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143489/creating-an-abstract-syntax-tree-from-a-stack#comment48396078_30143489), you need to define operator precedence rules, and add parentheses as necessary. The simplest approach would be to add a left parenthesis before each time you go left, and add a right parenthesis after each time you return from the right.

**Edit**

Also note that `1 2 X 3 4 X A *` isn't valid rpn, whereas `1 2 X 3 4 X A` is (because the extra `*` has no matching right operator).

**Edit 2**

A solution for supporting multi-digit numbers could be to use strings instead of characters to represent all tokens. You would need to change all occurences of `char` with `char *` in:

- The definitions of `struct snode` and `struct tnode`
- The argument to `push()` and `create_node()`
- The return value from `peek()`.
- The variable `value` in `main()` and `top` in `build_tree()`.

In addition, you would need to change `value = argv[i][0]` to simply `value = argv[i]` (I would also suggest removing the `const` qualifier from the `argv` argument to `main()`, unless you want to be const-correct). You would also need to change the operator equality check. For example, you could do:

```
int
is_operator(char *tok)
{
  return !strcmp(tok, "A") || !strcmp(tok, "S") || !strcmp(tok, "X") || !strcmp(tok, "D") || !strcmp(tok, "M");
}
```

and then simply write `if (is_operator(top))` in `build_tree()`.

Finally, you would need to change the `printf()` format string from `%c` to `%s`.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part. I edited my post so there is no extra  " * "

Comment: Im also confused on your explanation on how to fix the string problem I'm having.

Comment: Yes, I see now that you need to do additional changes. If you want to support multi-digit numbers, you can no longer simply represent the tokens as characters. Maybe it would be better just to use the strings? If so, you would need to change the equality tests for your operators with calls to `strcmp()`.

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation of how to do it with strings.